# searching within XML files

Tags: javascript, node.js, xml

I have ~250K XML files, each of them named with a UUID, and I want to do a full text search on these files and identify the UUID of the matching files. What is the best strategy for indexing them in a `nodejs` enviroment?

I could import the files into some database (say, SQLite), and then employ a full text search module (FTS5 in the case of SQLite). But I would have to ignore the XML tags somehow.

Or, I could use some kind of XMLPath module for nodejs to extract only the text and store that in the database along with the filename, and so on.

Or, even better would be if I could avoid importing in the database altogether since that way I wouldn't have to deal with the complexity of importing new records into the db.

Suggestions for strategy welcome.

Comment: Much depends on your requirements, including the environment you're going to deploy your app to.

If you're already comfortable using SQLite - great.  Otherwise, you might wish to consider something like [Lucene](https://lucene.apache.org/): https://www.npmjs.com/package/lucene

Answer (score 2):

There are three steps:

1. Use an XML parser to read the XML files
2. Log the UUID and files location into a db table (ID(INT),UUID(varchar unique), files location (json)). If UUID exist add the file into the files location column
3. After processing you have all the files location that have the same UUID in the same row.

You can checkout my `npm`:
 XML parser [link](https://www.npmjs.com/package/big-xml-notify)

Comment: yea, but how do I do the full text search? How do I find all the files with the term "foo" in them?

Comment: @punkish use regex to search through each record that contains "foo" https://www.npmjs.com/package/regex

Answer (score 1):

Based on your reply to Marcia Ong's answer, I'm no longer sure exactly what your question is.  So here's the "big picture":

1. You've got a bunch of XML files with a bunch of information in them.  The most efficient way to *retrieve* information is to somehow *index* those files.
2. A prerequisite for "indexing" is to "parse" the XML.  I believe that's the gist of Marcia Ong's reply. It sounds like a good suggestion.
3. Another issue: how do you build your index.  What *IS* your index?  That's the gist of my comment.  [SQLite + FTS5](https://sqlite.org/fts5.html) could be a good choice, [Lucene](http://lucene.apache.org/) could also work.  You have many options.  Much depends on your requirements, including the environment you're going to deploy your app to.
4. Yet another issue to consider: do you want to physically store the XML in the same place as your index (e.g. a SQLite database), or will your index simply "link" to the XML file?  For example, a filepath on a network share, or a relative path on your web server, etc.
5. The final issue: Q: How does your app query the index, and return the results?  A: "It depends".  It depends entirely on what technology you choose to index with, what language your app is programmed in, what information you actually want to retrieve from your XML, and many many other variables.
6. For example:

   1. Suppose you're on a Linux server, and suppose you choose Lucene (SQLite runs on Linux too, BTW...)
   2. You might have a nightly batch job to parse your XML files and update your indexes.
   3. Your app might do one of the following things:

      1. Query Lucene to identify the file,
      2. Use an NPM XML package to load the link as an XML document, and then
      3. Use the same XML library to make an XPath query for the specific data you wish to read from the XML file.

Answer (score 0):

You should load the XML files into an XML database. The most popular XML databases today seem to be BaseX, eXist, and MarkLogic. The first two are open source, the last is commercial. I believe that all of them offer full text searching capability as well as (and integrated with) XQuery. You will need to configure the chosen database to define how you want the data indexed.

(Relational databases such as Oracle, SQL Server, and DB2 also offer XML add-ons, but I wouldn't go that route because of the complexity).

Answer (score 0):

I have decided to go with SQLite3/FTS5 route. I parse the XML files with `xml2js` and store them in SQLite. I have a virtual table with the full text index that I can search really fast. On [Michael Kay's](https://stackoverflow.com/users/415448/michael-kay) [suggestion](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54386815/183692), I tried [BaseX](http://basex.org/download/) but there simply was no comparison. BaseX took ~32 mins to import ~250K XML files to create a ~6GB database. Search for a term took 2m 44s. The SQLite db with the FTS5 tables is about ~9GB. The same search takes 0.001s.

### BaseX

Timing:
- Parsing: 34.15 ms
- Compiling: 28.32 ms
- Evaluating: 163172.13 ms
- Printing: 537.65 ms
- Total Time: 163772.26 ms

### SQLite3

Run Time: real 0.001 user 0.000790 sys 0.000165